# Eclipse: How to set file encoding based on file extension

Tags: eclipse, file-encodings

## Problem

I have an eclipse project that is committed to source control.

The project looks something like this:

```
MyProject
    .classpath
    .project
    src/
        com/myCompany/code
            DoStuff.java
            DoOtherStuff.java
            someText.foo
    conf
        someOtherTextFile.foo
```

As you can see we have files of file extension foo.  The foo files use a different file encoding (ISO-8859-1) then the rest of the files in my project.  I want to configure eclipse to use ISO-8859-1 whenever those files are opened.

Here are the options that I have found so far:

## Solution 1 - Mark each file one by one

`Right Click File -> Properties -> Text file encoding -> Other: ISO-8859-1`

This then adds a line to `.settings/org.eclipse.core.resources.prefs`:

```
encoding//conf/someOtherTextFile.foo=ISO-8859-1
```

This solution works ok, but I need to do it for every foo file in my project and **I need to make sure that no one ever forgets to do it when they add a new foo file**.

## Solution 2 - Configure it in my workplace settings

This is done like this:

> Open the Eclipse Preferences and go to 'General > Content Types'.
>
> Select the type of the file, for example 'Text'
>
> In the File Associations area click 'Add' and add '*.foo'. Enter
>   'ISO-8859-1' in the 'Default Encoding' field.
>
> Click OK and you should be set.

([Thanks greg-449 for clarifying how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33640083/eclipse-how-to-set-file-encoding-based-on-file-extension/33640588#33640588)).

This solution does not work for my team because we don't commit the Eclipse workspace settings into source control (we only commit the project settings).

## What I really want to do

I would like to be able to say that all files **in the project** ending with .foo should be displayed with the encoding ISO-8859-1.  I need to configure this at the **project** level because my team commits project settings into source control but not workspace settings.

Any hints on how to do this?

Answer (score -1):

Greg-449 already explained you the steps, I am pasting the same explanation with screenshots:

Windows -> Preference -> General -> Content Types -> Text ->Add -> *.foo -> ok -> click on *.foo and fill the Default encoding as 'ISO-8859-1' -> update -> ok

[image: Preferences]

[image: Content Types]

[image: File association]

[image: File encoding]

Comment: @BirkramKundu - Thanks for the diagram.  This solution is the same as what I described in "Solution 2" and doesn't answer the question.